# Number of multidimensional lattice paths that go slightly over diagonal

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm looking for two things and, in advance, sorry for the quality of my explanation of the problem.

First is the formula to count the number of paths on an m-dimensional lattice of size n, but the paths are allowed to go "slightly" over the diagonal (let's call this number K(n,m)).

By slightly I mean that if we start at (0,0) and end at (n,n) then the path can cross points (i,i+1) and it can do that multiple times, but it can't cross points (i,i+2) (i,i+3) and so on (this is the 2-D case example).

I know how to count it when we can't go over the diagonal for m=2 (Catalan numbers) and for m>2 (generalized Catalan numbers ([link to OEIS](https://oeis.org/A060854))).

I also know how to count it for m=2 (it's Catalan numbers but shifted one term) and for when n=2 (simple factorial), but I can't seem to crack it for n>2,m>2.

Also, unlike generalized Catalan numbers, for which C(n,m) = C(m,n) this is not symmetrical.

For m=3 the first few terms are: 6, 57, 684, 9481, 145078.

For m=4 the first few terms are: 24, 1145, 77664, 6563518.

The second question is because I'm not sure the first question is exactly what I want. I mean, the first few terms above are most likely correct, but I'm not sure if solving the first question will actually yield those sequences, hence the second question.

Let's start with what I know.

In the 2-D case the n-th Catalan number is the number of 2n-long binary sequences, where up to i-th position the number of ones does not exceed the number of zeroes.

In the 3-D case for n we have 3n-long ternary sequences, where up to i-th position there can be no more ones than zeroes and no more twos than ones.

And so on for m-dimensions.

Those I know how to count (Catalan numbers and generalized Catalan numbers).

What I want to have:

For 2-D case: the number of binary sequences, where up to the i-th position there can be ONE more ones than zeroes (as I said before, those are just 1-term-shifted Catalan numbers).

For general m dimensions this restriction is more complex. Below we assume m*n-long sequence with exactly n zeroes, n ones, n twos and so on.

Let $O_k(i)$ be the number of Occurrences of the symbol (digit) k up to the i-th position.

Let $A_k(i)$ be the number of Allowed occurrences of k given the sequence up to i-th position.

If $A_k(i) > O_k(i)$ then the next symbol in sequence (on position i+1) can be k.

Now $A_k(i)$ depends on two things: how many k digits we have ALREADY and how many we CAN have of the previous (k-1) digit.

The exact rules are: (1) we can put at most one more of the same digit than we currently have (aside from the fact that we can't have more than n of the same digit) and (2) the number of possible k digits cannot be more than the number of possible k-1 digits. In other words:

$A_0(i) = O_0(i) + 1$  (if we have some zeroes, then the next symbol can also be a zero (provided we don't go over the lattice))

$A_k(i) = \min \{ O_k(i) + 1 , A_{k-1}(i) \}, k>0$

I know this is probably confusing, so a less formal description:

"if up to the i-th position digit k occurs F times, then digit k+1 can occur F+1 times, but this doesn't extend further: digits k+2, k+3 and so on are also restricted to F+1 occurrences, not F+2 or F+3...

...moreover, if say, k+4 digit occurs only G times ($G<F$), then k+5 and further digits are from now on restricted to G+1 occurrences, not F+1."

I know this is difficult and poorly explained, but I'll be very grateful for any insight into this problem.